# Cannot "pip install pynvx"

Tags: python, cmake, pip

I'm currently doing a project to learn how to use deepfake in videos, but encountered some problems setting up. I ran this command: `pip3 install pynvx` and also tried `pip install pynvx`, but none seems to work.

It spits out this error, hopefully someone could bless me with your skill:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:faceswap yuxin$ pip3 install pynvx 
 Collecting pynvx
  Using cached 
 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/c6/90f26fee13f4b264946f74ece86b815cb01cc07035c2c5c80ab82f690a4f/pynvx-0.0.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pynvx
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pynvx ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-wheel-ij1brnnf --python-tag cp37:
  Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044
  -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 (found version "3.7.1")
  -- Found PythonLibs: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
  -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
  -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
  -- pybind11 v2.3.dev0
  -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
  -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
  -- LTO enabled
  CMake Error at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:696 (message):
    Specify CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py", line 107, in <module>
      "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 188, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py", line 32, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py", line 56, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pynvx
  Running setup.py clean for pynvx
Failed to build pynvx
Installing collected packages: pynvx
  Running setup.py install for pynvx ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-record-ufc9w816/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044
    -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044
    -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 (found version "3.7.1")
    -- Found PythonLibs: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
    -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
    -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
    -- pybind11 v2.3.dev0
    -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
    -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
    -- LTO enabled
    CMake Error at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:696 (message):
      Specify CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py", line 107, in <module>
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py", line 32, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py", line 56, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-record-ufc9w816/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/30/xz4gwwrs655bvkh28n60p3b00000gp/T/pip-install-zquaz24q/pynvx/
```

I have no idea what's going on, googled around but can't seem to find anything that helps, so I would really appreciate any help given. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should *"Specify CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR"* as pointed out by the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, solved it, I google pynvx and a PyPi page popped up, went to Downloads Page and downloaded their `pynvx-0.0.4.tar.gz` file, and installed it using `$pip install pynvx-0.0.4.tar.gz`

Thank you to @a_guest for your help top!